# how calculate size of memory that allocated from create specific windows object?

Tags: debugging, windbg, driver

how calculate size of memory that allocated from create specific windows object
e.g.
how memory allocated when createsemaphore API is called?
there are any document that describe for all objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The allocation for most executive objects (like semaphores) is done inside the `ObCreateObject()` function. As you can see in [`ObCreateObject()`'s prototype](http://www.osronline.com/showThread.cfm?link=3787#T2), one of the parameters is `ObjectSizeToAllocate`.

When a function like [`NtCreateSemaphore()`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FSemaphore%2FNtCreateSemaphore.html) is called, it calls `ObCreateObject()` with the size of the kernel object to be created (for example, [`sizeof(KSEMAPHORE)`](http://msdn.moonsols.com/win7rtm_x86/KSEMAPHORE.html)) as the value for `ObjectSizeToAllocate`.

So the easiest way to answer your question is to set a breakpoint on `ObCreateObject()` and examine the value of `ObjectSizeToAllocate` when it's called to create your object of interest.